# $100$ prisoners problem - But here they write their guess on paper

Tags: probability, combinatorics, puzzle

A variant of the $100$ prisoners problem.

$100$ prisoners are given each either a white hat or a black hat. They can see each other's hat but not their own and they cannot communicate.

Each prisoner **must write**(not yell like in the classic one) on a piece of paper his guess for the color of his hat, which can be "black", "white" or "pass" ($3$ options instead of $2$ in the classic one).

If not all prisoners choose "pass" and all those who didn't pass guess correctly, then all prisoners are sent free.

Invent a strategy for the prisoners that will maximize their chance of getting free, assuming the hats are chosen randomly.

**My current thoughts:** It is possible to find a strategy in which the chances increase with the number of prisoners. For $3$ prisoners a strategy might be to choose "pass" if the colors of the two hats are different, otherwise to choose the opposite of the same color. This gives a $75$% chance of getting free.

Comment: Do you consider all configurations of hats equally likely (i.e. hats are chosen by coinflip) or maliciously chosen to minimize your chance of victory? Your example seems to indicate the former.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof Former

Comment: Strategies where only one prisoner potentially votes cannot exceed 50% in chance

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof Do you know what's the strategy for n = 100 prisoners?

Comment: No, I don't. But check out the duplicate thread.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof I did. please help me to re-open this thread. the duplicate doesn't help me to find strictly the bound for $n = 100.$

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS The thread discusses that the $n=100$ case is an open problem. In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3272959/hat-guessing-with-100-hats-case/3272988#3272988), I give a strategy with a $98.4\%$ success rate, and prove that no strategy can achieve a $99.01\%$ success rate, so my strategy is at least very close to optimal.